# How can I pre-authorize a client app for my user on my oauth provider that uses doorkeeper?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth-2.0

I've written an oauth provider that is meant to work with several of my company's web applications. I am using the doorkeeper gem, which has worked well so far.

Typical behavior is for a user to go to the client application, get redirected to the provider to sign in, confirm that the client application is authorized to access that user's information, and get redirected back to the client application. However, I'd like to skip the step of the user confirming the client application. I'd like to do it for them, so there is no prompt.

I tried to mimic code I [found here](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/blob/master/app/controllers/doorkeeper/authorizations_controller.rb) with something like:

```
Doorkeeper::Application.all.each do |application|
  auth_params = {response_type: 'code', client_id: application.uid, redirect_uri: application.redirect_uri}
  client = Doorkeeper::OAuth::Client.find(application.uid)
  authorization = Doorkeeper::OAuth::AuthorizationRequest.new(client, user, auth_params)
  authorization.authorize
end
```

but that didn't work, it still gives the user the Authorize/Deny prompt for a client app. Suggestions?

Comment: If you do not want a user confirmation, you shouldn't use the authorization code grant scenario. Instead, you should choose the client credentials grant scenario (section 4.4 in the OAuth2 spec) which is designed to do exactly what you want. However, I'm not familiar with DoorKeeper, you should find out how to do it in rails.

Comment: I am doing it in rails. Doorkeeper is a gem: https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper. I have read the OAuth2 spec and I don't want the client credentials grant scenario. I've spent some time implementing OAuth myself. However, this isn't a primary part of my job and I'd rather not have to write it myself (and maintain it) if I can tweak something that is maintained to my needs.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

OAuth has the [Resource Owner Credentials Grant](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-30#section-4.4) flow for this, which Doorkeeper supports. Basically you request an access token with the user credentials (username and password). This way you skip the user confirmation and you also don't need a callback URL.

To configure Doorkeeper:

```
Doorkeeper.configure do
  resource_owner_from_credentials do |routes|
    User.authenticate!(params[:username], params[:password]) # change this if needed
  end
end
```

Example token request:

```
curl -i https://example.com/oauth/token \
     -F grant_type=password \
     -F client_id=<client_id> \
     -F client_secret=<client_secret> \
     -F username=user@example.com \
     -F password=password
```

If your OAuth client applications are Rails applications you can use the [oauth2](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/) gem for this:

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new('client_id', 'client_secret', :site => "https://example.com")
access_token = client.password.get_token('user@example.com', 'password')
```

Also see Doorkeepers wiki:

https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/wiki/Using-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-flow

Comment: If you want to go this route, you'll need to have login screen in your client app.

Answer (score 13):

#### Doorkeeper 0.6.7 provides configure option to do this.

To configure Doorkeeper:

```
Doorkeeper.configure do
  skip_authorization do
    true
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 13):

You can have your app preauthorize either *all* client apps by adding

```
skip_authorization do
  true
 end
```

to doorkeeper initializer, or on a per app basis by adding a boolean `preauthorized` to the Doorkeeper `oauth_applications` table. Then add something like this to the initializer:

```
skip_authorization do |resource_owner, client|
  client.application.preauthorized?
 end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can acquire the token for your application to bypass that confirmation screen a post to /oauth/token.  Tweak it to your liking.

In your client application:

```
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'

client_id = '4ea1b...'
client_secret = 'a2982...'

response = RestClient.post 'http://localhost:3000/oauth/token', {
  grant_type: 'client_credentials',
  client_id: client_id,
  client_secret: client_secret
}
token = JSON.parse(response)["access_token"]
```

Now you can request access to protected resources that does not require a resource owner:

```
RestClient.get 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/profiles.json', { 'Authorization' => "Bearer #{token}" }
```

Source: https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/wiki/Client-Credentials-flow

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it seems, your company has many application and you wish to use one authentication platform for all of these.

Now, I would presume you would want to have the login screen at one place (presumably at the authenticator app). If that's the case, you will NOT be able to use [Resource Owner Credentials Grant](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Using-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-flow) flow for this.

The best way would be have a list of trustworthy clients and skip authorisation conditionally as follows:

```
# config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb

Doorkeeper.configure do
  skip_authorization do |resource_owner, client|
    client.uid == "client application id of the trusted app goes here"
  end
end
```

If you want to have the clients have their own login screens, the Resource Owner Credentials Grant flow would suffice.